# Как передать несколько значений в IN оператор из строчного параметра процедуры?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В хранимой процедуре есть запрос, который ищет по входному параметру `input_param`:

```
 procedure tst (input_param in varchar2)
    is
        select
            so_much_columns
        from
            so_much_tables
        where
            value in (input_param);
    end tst;
```

При вызове процедуры нужно передавать два значения как параметр:

```
call tst.tst (input_param => 'Tst1, Tst2');
```

Но такое, конечно, не работает, т.к. для `IN` оператора `input_param` это одно значение.

Как можно решить, есть ли уже какие-то решения для этого случая?

Comment: Для задачи:  "разбить строку по запятой на подстроки" есть 1001 решение, быстрых и не очень, красивых и не очень. Найдёте по кл. словам -  "split comma delimited string into rows".  Я дал ответ с самым простым на мой взгляд решением.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо поделить строку переданную как параметр по запятой на табличные записи.
Например так:

```sql
create table t1 as 
    select rownum id, cast (column_value as varchar2 (5)) value
    from xmlTable ('"Tst1", "Tst2"');

create or replace procedure getrows (params varchar2) is
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for
    select id, value
    from t1
    where value in (
        select trim (column_value) params 
        from xmlTable (('"'||replace (params, ',', '","')||'"'))
    );
    dbms_sql.return_result (rc);
end;
/

exec getrows (params => 'Tst1, Tst2')
```

Результат:

```
        ID VALUE
---------- -----
         1 Tst1 
         2 Tst2
```

Comment: Отличное решение, помогло с моим кейсом, спасибо. Позволяет не сильно терять в скорости, даже если больше одной входящей переменной