# Как передать несколько параметров через строковую перменную для подстановки в SQL операток IN

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Не понимаю как разбить по строкам

Нужно что бы выводил как в запросе (если сможете то сделать без дубликатов)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при запуске процедуры происходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот это надо разбить по запитым как я понял
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
create or replace procedure FindDish (idtype in number, ingrlist in varchar2, idseason in number, timecooking in number) 
IS
select_query varchar2(4000);
create_query varchar2(4000);
total varchar2(4000);
begin
select_query := 'Select Name FROM INGR, dish, seas, seq where dish.id = seq.dish_id and dish.seas_id = seas.seas_id and ingr.INGR_ID = seq.INGR_ID and ingr_name in (' || ingrlist ||')';
create_query := 'Create table T_'|| generate_name(10) || ' AS ' || select_query;
dbms_output.enable;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(select_query);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_query;
end;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_name(len number) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
my_str varchar2(255);
BEGIN
FOR i in 1..len LOOP
my_str := my_str || dbms_random.string(
CASE WHEN dbms_random.VALUE(0, 1) < 0.5 THEN 'l' ELSE 'x' END, 1);
END LOOP;
RETURN my_str;
END;
```

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement

Comment: @Mike Зачем на сторонние ресурсы направлять, если у нас уже есть [тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1106096), почти один-в-один с текущим вопросом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в передаче строкового параметра с возможными значениями оператора `IN` для подстановки в запрос, вместо

```
'Сахар, Банан'
```

должно быть

```
'''Сахар'', ''Банан'''
```

В первом случае строка воспринимается как одно значение и выполняется

```
select * from <...> where ingr_name in ('Сахар, Банан')
```

а правильно

```
select * from <...> where ingr_name in ('Сахар', 'Банан')
```

Чтобы добиться корректной подстановки необходимо каждое отдельное значение заключить в кавычки, предварительно их удвоив.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from INGR
where ingr_name in (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@ingrlist, CHAR(13) ))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Оформите ответ более детально

Comment: @insolor Да лучше удалить, чем править, т.к. совсем не в тему, это диалект SQL-Server. Тип, как проголосовать за удаление не тратя репутации: временно поставить минус, обновить страницу, в появившейся кнопке [удалить] дать голос на удаление, минус отозвать обратно.